# ArduinoJSON; test if property exists in JSON / Conversion

Tags: c, json, arduino

I have code running on a microcontroller, and I am parsing the control command it will receive.

The command is JSON, and looks approximately like this...

```
{[PARAMTER_1]:[VALUE_1], [...] , [PARAMTER_N]:[VALUE_N]}
```

So it could be...

```
{"opMode"=1, "StringA" = "Hello"}
```

or it could be

```
{"brightness"=5, "StringB"="Goodbye"}
```

How can I test to see if a parameter is included?

For example, if I process with this code:

```
String command = <JSON COMMAND>
char conString[200];

command.toCharArray(conString, sizeof(conString));
StaticJsonBuffer<1000> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(conString);
```

How can I test the resultant root["PARAMTER"] outputs to see if they existed?  The problem is that if I just do something like...

```
resultString = root["StringA"];
resultInt    = root["opMode"];
```

If those exist but are "" and 0, they will return the same values as if they were not included in the JSON in the first place.

Do I have to use something like command.indexOf("opMode") on the raw JSON string to make sure it's there?  (In this example, that would work.  But with more complicated JSON, that seems to be a lot of work to make sure a response is valid/existing)

Comment: Also, for a string it's not quite as important, as I could interpret a blank string as a NULL.

However, zero is a valid numeric type, and a common one.  So other than shifting and essentially escaping values of zero on both sides, it would be nice to validate the existence of the parameter in the JSON or JsonObject.

Comment: Dammit.  I searched for this for an hour; found JsonObject.containsKey() just now, and it works.  I swear posting to forums makes my google-Fu better.

Thanks for reading.  I'll leave it here in case it helps others.